# Creating raster object in R (raster package) by browsing directory

Tags: raster, r

I am working with raster data (.tif) in R using the Raster Package, and I know how to create a raster object through

```
r <- raster(filename)
```

I am working with models with some long filenames, and so having to type out the filename is slowing me down. e.g.

```
filename <- "wc2.1_2.5m_bioc_CNRM-CM6-1_ssp245_2041-2060.tif"
```

Is there a way to create a raster object using my windows browser, or a simpler way to create raster objects, when I have multiple filenames with unwieldy names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `list.files()` from base R allows to list files that match a pattern, in your case it would be `.tif`, or, if you only want those that start with `wc` it would be `wc.*tif`, using regular expressions. The argument `full.names = T` will give you complete names with directories, which helps to call these file names in functions; `recursive = T` tells the function to search in sub-directories

`file_list = list.files(pattern = ".tif", full.names = T, recursive = T)`

then you may read and stack the files using a for loop, such as:

```
library(raster)

raster::stack(file_list)
```

Comment: You do not need a loop to create a stack, you can just pass the vector eg., `stack(list.files(pattern = ".tif", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))`

Comment: that package is always impressive

Comment: Thanks to both Elio and Diaz, this is precisely the kind of thing I'm looking for. It'll take me a little bit of practice, but this is great!